# Count lines of non-terminating input

Tags: bash, wc

Is there any way to count the lines of a non-terminating input source? For example, I want to run the following for a period of time to count the number of requests:

```
ngrep -W byline port 80 and dst host 1.2.3.4 | grep ":80" | wc
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kill that, I'm not going to get any output from `wc`. I would rather avoid creating a file if I can.

Comment: Just a reminder, that since it’s a stream `sed -n '$='` may be faster than `wc` on large data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from the terminal sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process group.  If you want `wc` to survive this event and produce output, you need to have it ignore the signal.

The solution is to run `wc` in a subshell and have its parent shell set `SIGINT` to be ignored before running `wc`.  `wc` will inherit this setting and not die when `SIGINT` is sent to the process group.  The rest of the pipeline will die, leaving `wc` reading from a pipe that has no process on the other end.  This will cause `wc` to see `EOF` on the pipe and it will then output its counts and exit.

```
ngrep -W byline port 80 and dst host 1.2.3.4 | grep ":80" | (trap '' INT ; wc)
```

Comment: You may want to include `grep` in that subshell or add the `--line-buffered` option (if GNU grep). Otherwise, you wont count the lines stored in `grep`'s output buffer that have not been flushed yet by the time of the CTRL-C.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can keep counting afer reading the current count:

My non-terminating test input source is a ping:

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1  
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
^C
```

With other solutions, we had to decide when to read out the line count, and were interrupting the running command.
But ideally we would just like to know the current line count, right?

So, why not just count the lines? The right tool for the job is [`nl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/nl.1.html), adding the current count in front of each line:

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1 | nl
     1  PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
     2  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
     3  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
     4  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
     5  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
     6  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
     7  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
     8  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
     9  64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ ngrep -W byline port 80 and dst host 1.2.3.4 | grep ":80" |
perl -nle 'system("clear");print $.'
```

`perl` will keep track what lines you had, clear old output before print it.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re willing to specify a time limit (rather than just doing it off the cuff),
you could use this trick

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 300; kill $cmdpid) & exec ngrep (ngrep args) ) | grep ":80" | wc
```

inspired by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/806804/354511) to a recent question
over on SU; essentially [How to stop a running program after 5 minutes and continue?](https://superuser.com/q/806794/354511)